# How to solve library error calling the method c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I've made a library and I've imported it adding a reference in the project and put `using` the namespace of my library, but when I'm trying to use a method it shows me an error.
"The type or namespace name 'UploadFiles' does not exist in the namespace 'MyGoogleUDS'(are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Project:

```
using MyGoogleUDS;
```

error on this call:

```
MyGoogleUDS.UploadFiles("..\\" + asset.Name);
```

My library:

```
namespace MyGoogleUDS
{
    public class MyGoogleUDS
    {
        public static void UploadFiles(string path)
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: It seems you're calling the function directly on the namespace name. This should be a class or object name instead.

Comment: Assuming you can change the library, I'd recommend renaming either the namespace or the type. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class name and namespace name is same, so you need to use namespace aliasing or you need to add namespace before class name

something like

```
MyGoogleUDS.MyGoogleUDS.UploadFiles("..\\" + asset.Name);
```

Namespace aliasing,

```
using namespaceName = MyGoogleUDS;

namespaceName.MyGoogleUDS.UploadFiles("..\\" + asset.Name);
```

> As @JonSkeet suggested, I recommend you to update either namespace
>   name or class name to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it like this

```
MyGoogleUDS.MyGoogleUDS.UploadFiles("..\\" + asset.Name);
```

Another problem could be that you forgot to add a reference to your .dll in the project